Plotly Dash Graph Showing Days That Haven't Occured Yet This Month
I have a small issue that I have run into with my code. Below it is listed:
else:
            dff = df.query(f"year == {year_value}" and f"month == {month_value}" and f"desk == '{desk_value}'")
            day_totals = dff['day'].value_counts(sort=False)
            unique_days = dff['day'].unique()
            fig = px.bar(dff, x = unique_days, y = list(day_totals), text_auto=True)
            fig.update_layout(
                xaxis = dict(
                    tickmode = 'array',
                    tickvals = unique_days,
                    ticktext = unique_days,
                    title= "Day"
                ),
                yaxis = dict(
                    tickmode = 'array',
                    tickvals = list(day_totals),
                    ticktext = list(day_totals),
                    title= "patrons Helped"
                )
            )
            fig.update_traces(
                marker_color = '#376062'
            )
            return fig  

The F strings are values that are gathered from a dropdown menu and it is only in this situation where I try to filter by desk that this occurs. Essentially, even though today is the 20th it is showing data for the 21st, 22nd, 23rd, etc. I only want values associated with the month selected to display.
I only recently noticed this and haven't tried much. I do not want to break it entirely which I have a bad feeling I will. I am just looking for some direction of where to begin fixing this so that it displays accurate data.

One way to solve this is to generate all of the dates in the month and use those values to create the chart. You can create a date range index by supplying the year and month and doing some calculations to get the last day of the month. By adding 31 days to the start of the current month, you can find the next month's number. The - timedelta(days=1) moves from the first day of the next month to the last day of the current month.
all_days = pandas.date_range(
    start=date(year_value, month_value, 1),
    end=date(year_value, (date(year_value, month_value, 1) + timedelta(days=31)).month, 1
    ) - timedelta(days=1),
).day

Once you have all the days in the current month, you can reindex and fill the gaps in your data like this:
day_totals = dff["day"].value_counts().reindex(all_days, fill_value=0)
unique_days = all_days.values

I had an additional issue with the df.query not correctly filtering the month values so I changed the syntax to be one large f-string with the and keywords included in the string.
Here is the output:

Here is the full example:
import random
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas
import plotly.express as px


def get_df():
    # Create some fake data for an example
    date_cursor = date(2024, 1, 1)
    desks = ["0001", "0002", "0003"]
    records = []
    while date_cursor <= date(2024, 6, 25):
        for desk in desks:
            for _ in range(random.randint(0, 5)):
                records.append(
                    [date_cursor.year, date_cursor.month, date_cursor.day, desk]
                )
        date_cursor += timedelta(days=1)
    return pandas.DataFrame(records, columns=["year", "month", "day", "desk"])


df = get_df()


year_value = 2024
month_value = 6
desk_value = "0001"


dff = df.query(
    f"year == {year_value} and month == {month_value} and desk == '{desk_value}'"
)

all_days = pandas.date_range(
    start=date(year_value, month_value, 1),
    end=date(
        year_value, (date(year_value, month_value, 1) + timedelta(days=31)).month, 1
    )
    - timedelta(days=1),
).day

day_totals = dff["day"].value_counts().reindex(all_days, fill_value=0)
unique_days = all_days.values
fig = px.bar(dff, x=unique_days, y=list(day_totals), text_auto=True)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode="array", tickvals=unique_days, ticktext=unique_days, title="Day"
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode="array",
        tickvals=list(day_totals),
        ticktext=list(day_totals),
        title="patrons Helped",
    ),
)
fig.update_traces(marker_color="#376062")
fig.show()


After reviewing the code, the problem wasn't that it was showing days that hadn't happened yet; rather that it was showing data that wasn't accurate to the filters because part of the code was broken. Thus it was just displaying the previous data that had been selected before a value was selected for desk value. I changed the df.query syntax from what is listed above to (for example) 'year == @year_value and desk == @desk_value' with the values being variables that were set to equal data coming from inputs of the function to update the fig.
